# Limit to number of "named ranges" in Range method

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code:

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Workbooks("import sheet.xls").Sheets("import").Range("project_name,project_author,project_code,project_breaker,default_fault_ac_mcb,default_fault_ac_mccb,default_fault_dc,default_fault_acb,default_rvdrop,default_svdrop,default_eff,default_pfactor,default_ratio,default_freq,default_sfactor_ac,default_spfactor")

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    MsgBox cell
Next cell
```

Now `project_name`, `project_author`, etc. are different named ranges in the sheet. The problem is when I add another named range to the above list (already defined), I get a runtime error 1004 ("select method of range class failed").

Is there a limit to the number of named ranges one can add to range object?

Comment: If I add more than 16 named ranges then it gives me a different error. It say `Application-defined` or `object-defined error`. Le tme check this one out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on why this happens but I am still looking.

However this works. You can combine the range using `UNION`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, newRng As Range

    Set rng = Sheets("import").Range("project_name,project_author,project_code,project_breaker,default_fault_ac_mcb,default_fault_ac_mccb,default_fault_dc,default_fault_acb,default_rvdrop,default_svdrop,default_eff,default_pfactor,default_ratio,default_freq,default_sfactor_ac,default_spfactor")

    Set newRng = Union(rng, Sheets("import").Range("default_sid"))

    For Each cell In newRng.Cells
        MsgBox cell
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**: I couldn't find any Microsoft document which describes this behavior, but after some experimentation, I can confirm that the maximum number of named ranges one can add to range object is 16. This behavior can be seen in in Excel 2003, 2007, and 2010.

Strangely this behavior was **not** replicated in **Excel 2011** (MAC). I tested with 19 names and it worked.

**MORE UPDATE**

After more testing, I discovered that if you name your ranges as `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3` etc then I was able to add more named Ranges in Excel 2003-2007-2010. So it has to do something with the naming of the names.

I have filed a bug with Microsoft.

**SAMPLE FILE FOR TESTING**:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=cdd3f8abe20bbe3b&resid=CDD3F8ABE20BBE3B!157&parid=CDD3F8ABE20BBE3B!150&authkey=!ADP_QVBopsqenBA

Comment: @siddarth Rout i did the same thing but instead of doing it in code..i made the range in excel itself...

Comment: which part of code are you referring to? Did you try giving Small names to the `Named Ranges`?

Comment: actually i made a new named range in excel itself which consisted of all ranges which i wanted to check..

Comment: well yes now its working but now its one single range(The question still remains that microsoft is putting a limit to the number of named ranges that can be entered in the range method,isnt it? )

Comment: No, MS has not put a limit to the `number` of named ranges but to the `number of characters` in the names. See my comment `MORE UPDATE` in the above post.

Comment: but the names are delimited by a "," why isnt it taking sub ranges as different names?Why is it considering them as a single name?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: A blast from the past... Thanks for rectifying the formatting. Guess I was still a Newbie then :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not investigated your problem but the points below may give you and Sid some hints on the possible solution.

If you access `Rng.Address` there is a limit on the size of the string.  I have found comments on the internet claiming the limit is 253 but I do not believe this.  `Rng.Address` is always truncated at the end of a complete sub-range so the string you get back is syntactically correct just incomplete.  So the limit depends on the exact string size of the sub-ranges.

I had the opposite problem.  I had a sheet with thousands of rows.  I used AutoFilter to select the rows of interest and saved the range.  But `Rng.Address` only gave me the first 19 or so ranges of interest.  I had to use `For Each Cell In Rng` and assemble the range string to get the full string.

Your string is 255 characters long.  There is clearly no limit on the number of sub-ranges in a union.  You could try adding the sub-ranges to the union individually.

Best of luck.

PS If you want my assemble range string routine you are welcome.

Comment: I understand the point you are trying to make but what baffles me is that the same code works beautifully in Excel 2011.

Comment: Presumably there is a string limit in PC versions which the Mac version does not. There seem to be strange differences between the PC and Mac versions. Is this any stranger? Best of luck with your investigation.

Comment: `Is this any stranger?` Nah it is not :) The worst difference that I discovered was that if you protect your VBA in WinPC, you cannot use the same password to open the VBA in MAC!!!

Comment: I can live with MAC not having something which WinPC has. But the reverse? Too much for me to digest LOL

Comment: @TonyDallimore sorry for replying late..i was out of office..but i coudnt get your answer...why is there a limit to number of subranges???

Comment: I have found nothing that tells me the reason; Sid is more likely to be able to help you there. Also remember that I was working in the opposite direction. Using AutoFilter on a massive worksheet, I have created a union with **hundreds of sub-ranges** and I wanted the string address (`StrAddr = Range.Address`) but discovered this limit of around 255 characters. There was no obvious limit on the number of sub-ranges in a union only on the string representation. You attempted to build a union in a single statement of 255 characters so I suspected you had hit the limitation from the other side.

Comment: If I understand Sid's answer correctly, you can achieve the effect you seek by splitting the long string into sub-strings. The limit is not the number of sub-ranges in a union but the length of the input or output string. Good luck.